# Get a list of all the times a number divides another and the remainder

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I want to do is equally split a number, `total`, into a list such that the list consists as many times as possible of the same number, `split`,  and the sum of the list will be equal to `total`.

For example, given:

```
total = 120
split = 50
```

I would like to get a list as:

```
eqParts = [50, 50, 20]  # 50 + 50 + 20 = 120 = total
```

Because `50` can fit two times in `120` and the remainder is `20`.

Comment: A stack overflow post advised that's how you done a loop  - thanks for the advise though, will change that :) (Also edited the question so its more of a "question"£

Comment: @Tomerikoo Sorry, updated it now so it should make more sense :)

Comment: Your edits make sense, just found it difficult to describe what it was I was after! - i think @OneCricketeer answer below pretty much solves it!

Comment: you didn't you made it much clearer - thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you want modulo operations and the final remainder.

Checkout [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod)

```
>>> a = 120
>>> b = 50
>>> whole, remaining = divmod(a, b)
>>> whole*[b] + [remaining]
[50, 50, 20]
```